# The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength . while enable windows authentication

Tags: iis

I am facing an issue while deploying an application on IIS 8.5 (local host).

I have to enable the Windows authentication for the application. So I enabled the `windows authentication` in IIS.

At that time I got an error: `The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength`.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

In your web.config file set the length of query like

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" 
requestValidationMode="2.0" maxUrlLength="1024" maxQueryStringLength="2097150" />
```

Comment: That query string shouldn't be that long in the first place. Your solution is ridiculous.